# Remove core data item after being added SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Here's my code

**Coffee struct and core data NSManaged**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct CoffeeItem: Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var favorite: Bool
}

extension CoffeeItem {
    static func all() -> [CoffeeItem] {
        return [
            CoffeeItem(title: "Cappuccino", favorite: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Cappuccino")),
            CoffeeItem(title: "Macchiato", favorite: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Macchiato")),
            CoffeeItem(title: "Espresso", favorite: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Espresso")),
            CoffeeItem(title: "Ristretto", favorite: UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Ristretto"))
        ]
    }
}
```

.

```
import CoreData

class CoffeeFavorite: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title: String
}
```

**Main view**

```
struct CoffeeSection: View {
    //Core Data
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: CoffeeFavorite.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]) var coffeeFavorite: FetchedResults<CoffeeFavorite>

    @State var coffeeItems = CoffeeItem.all()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< self.coffeeItems.count) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(self.coffeeItems[item].title)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .padding()

                    Spacer()

                    Image(systemName: self.coffeeItems[item].favorite ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.addItem(item: self.coffeeItems[item].title)
                            self.coffeeItems[item].favorite.toggle()
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.coffeeItems[item].favorite, forKey: self.coffeeItems[item].title)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    func addItem(item: String) {
        let newItem = CoffeeFavorite(context: managedObjectContext)
        newItem.title = item
        saveFavorites()
    }
    func saveFavorites() {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Favorite view**

```
struct FavoritesList: View {
    //Core Data
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: CoffeeFavorite.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: false)]) var coffeeFavorite: FetchedResults<CoffeeFavorite>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(coffeeFavorite, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item.title)

            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
        }
    }

    func deleteItem(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        let source = indexSet.first!
        let favorites = coffeeFavorite[source]
        managedObjectContext.delete(favorites)

        saveFavorites()
    }

    func saveFavorites() {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I have a main view with 4 coffee items and a heart on the right that when is tapped it adds that item title to core data and I can see it in my favorite view. I can delete my core item from the favorite view with .onDelete(perform: ...) but I want to do the same in my main view by tapping the heart so when I toggle it I add and delete that item from core data.
How can I make it work simultaneously on both views??

Comment: Your example code seems to do persistence both via Core Data and UserDefaults...

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to handle small data with user defaults even if maybe it's better to do all with core data since I'm using it but I'm kinda new to core data and as I get more knowledge I will change it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete all items in Core Data that match a predicate:

```swift
private func deleteFavorite(title: String) throws {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CoffeeFavorite")
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", title)
    try managedObjectContext.execute(NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request))
}
```

Comment: you actually saved me, I've been trying to solve it for days! Thank you very much!!